# Trying to figure out how to animate the scrollTop only if the .rm-box element is below the scroll position of the window

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

   $(".rm").click(function() { 
      var bgVisible = $(".rm-box").is(":visible"); 
      $(".rm-box:visible").stop().slideUp("slow"); 
      $(".ps-box").hide(); 
      $(".na-box").hide(); 
      $(".bg-box").hide(); 
      $(".mr-box").hide(); 

   if (!bgVisible) {
```

> Would like to check here if .rm-box element is below the scroll position

```
      $(".rm-box").slideDown("slow"); $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(".rm").offset().top       }, 400); 
  return false; 
 } 
});
```

});

Comment: `if ($(".rm-box").offset().top > $(window).scrollTop())`

Comment: @adeneo  Fit it has an answer not a comment. Wait a second, 75k rep, you already know this. Sorry.

Comment: Roger, did adeneo answered your question ?